# Django, have model to be related to many instances of itself

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model:

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
```

I want it to have a `sub_industries` field that will hold all of its sub industries, which should be instances of `Industry` model.

I cannot be `ManyToMany` because each industry has only one parent industry.

Comment: you can use one to one than

Comment: you don't want to have a Onetomany relation either? because it seems that a Foreignkey can solve that for you, since the sub_industries hold all the sub for an Industry

Comment: ForeignKey should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys! `ForeignKey` seems to be doing a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ForeignKey` to itself with:

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    parent_industry = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        related_name='sub_industries'
    )
```

You can use `NULL`/`None` to express that an industry has no parent.

Comment: That is my solution so far. Now, I can access `sub_industries` in Industry like it's any other field, right?

Comment: @Karol: for a given `myindustry`, you can access it with `myindustry.sub_industries.all()`.